# calculate how many digits that agree after decimal point of two numbers in R

Tags: r, compare, decimal

I would like R to count the number of digits that are the same between two numbers and return the number of digits that are the same after the decimal point. For example:

```
a <- 0.1234567890
b <- 0.1234567891
```

Output:

```
9
```

9 digits are the same.

Thanks!

Comment: convert to `character` string then use `string distance`

Comment: Are you sure this is a very useful measure? After all `0.1 + 0.2` in R doesn't equal `0.3`. Are you trying to show how similar two numbers are?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about `floor(-log10(abs(a-b)))`?

Note there is always a risk with any calculation like this that there may be problems with floating point errors - see the example pointed out by John Paul below.

Comment: very fast and elegant answer. It's perfect!

Comment: really impressive!

Comment: `ceiling(-log10(abs(.3112-.3111))-1)` gives 4. Is that correct? I thought it should be 3.

Comment: I suspect any formula like this will always suffer from some floating point comparison problems.  Warning added above - thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 1):

Here is another (string-based) answer, that should not suffer from any floating-point comparison problems...

```
sum(sapply(1:20,function(i) grepl(substr(b,1,i),a)))-2
```

This compares all initial substrings of `b` (coerced to character) of length 1 to 20 (you could extend this), determines whether they are contained in `a`, returns the number of matches (i.e. the length of the longest substring of `b` contained in `a`) and subtracts 2 to allow for the initial `0.`

Comment: Nice one! This is also good to compare words and sentences without the -2 at the end.